# Moving Run and Debug section to Terminal Panel in VSCode

Tags: visual-studio-code, panel

Is there a way to move the "Run and Debug" section from the "Primary Sidebar" to the "Panel" (The panel which includes "Terminal" "Debug Console", etc.)?

Comment: No, some views, like the Explorer can be moved to that Panel.  But some views cannot, like Extensions or Run and Debug.  As close as you can get is to individually drag the Run and Debug's viewlets (like Watch, Variables, etc.) to the Panel.

Comment: That's not exactly what I meant to do, but it's the same as what Mark proposed. Thank you @starball